# Further data manipulation after using group_by in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm having some issues when further processing my data after using group by. For example this is my data, and my task is to group by Item, Sum QTY and choose min time_loc and dataframe is df.

| Item | Qty | time_loc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 | 15/07/2021 |
| Apple | 1 | 18/07/2021 |
| Apple | 1 | 19/07/2021 |
| Banana | 3 | 15/07/2021 |
| Banana | 4 | 18/07/2021 |

My code to group by looks like:

```
df <- group_by(df, Item, %>% 
    summarize(Qty = sum(Qty),time_loc = min(time_loc))
```

Now I'd like to do further operations with the desire outcome to create a flag = "Yes" when QTY > 5 and no otherwise:

| Item | Qty | time_loc | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 4 | 15/07/2021 | No |
| Banana | 7 | 15/07/2021 | Yes |

My code looks like:

```
df<- df %>% mutate(Flag = if_else( df$Qty > 5, "Yes","No"))
```

But keep getting this error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Flag`.
> x Input `Flag` can't be recycled to size 1.
> i Input `Flag` is `if_else(...)`.
> i Input `FLag` must be size 1, not 2.
> i The error occurred in group 1: Item = "Apple" , Qty = 4 , time_loc = 2021-07-15.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution based on `dplyr` library:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Item) %>% 
  mutate(time_loc = as.Date(time_loc, format="%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  summarise(Qty = sum(Qty), time_loc = min(time_loc), Flag = ifelse(Qty>5, "Yes", "No"))

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Item     Qty time_loc   Flag 
#   <chr>  <int> <date>     <chr>
# 1 Apple      4 2021-07-15 No   
# 2 Banana     7 2021-07-15 Yes
```

Comment: yes! This is working, I guess my mistake was to do df$Qty as it resulted passing on a vector